# Whatsapp link in WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, whatsapp

I'm working on an app now, which has a uiWebView that is loading a page which has a Whatsapp link.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php the_title(); ?>">
```

But because this link doesn't start with http://, the app/WebView doesn't open it in WhatsApp, does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIApplication to open the link to Whatsapp.

For example:

```
let title = "My Title"
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(title)") as! URL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(title)") as! URL)
}
```

And in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("Opened URL: \(url)")
    return true
}
```